# p:selectOneListbox ajax item delete changes scroll position to top

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, scroll, selectonelistbox

There is a p:selectOneListbox with about 20 items. The first 5 items can be viewed in the list and then the remaining can be scrolled to and selected. The list is ajaxified. A list item is selected and on clicking an ajax delete-button the item is deleted and the following item is selected. This works fine. But, the list's scroll bar moves to the top and the newly selected item is not visible - when items with index greater than 5. The app uses PrimeFaces 5.1.

I also tried this with Apache MyFaces 2.0 - using f:ajax, h:selectOneListbox and h:commandButton instead of the respective p: tags. The managed bean code remained the same. In this case it works fine - the scroll bar does not move to top (just adjusts as needed). I would like similar behaviour with Primefaces tags.

The JSF page code:

```
<p:selectOneListbox id="list" scrollHeight="100"
    value="#{bean.todo}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.data}" />
    <p:ajax process="@this" update="msg"
    listener="#{bean.valueChanged}" />
</p:selectOneListbox>

<br />
<p:commandButton value="Delete">
    <p:ajax process="@this" update="list msg"
    listener="#{bean.deleteListener}"/>
</p:commandButton>

<br /><br /><h:outputText id="msg" value="#{bean.message}" />
```

The bean code:

```
package example;

import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
import javax.faces.component.UIOutput;

@ManagedBean(name="bean")
@SessionScoped
public class TodosBean implements Serializable {

    private List<String> data;
    private String todo; // selected item value
    private String msg;

    public TodosBean() {
        loadData();
        String t = data.get(0);
        setTodo(t); // select the first item in the list
        setMessage(t);
    }

    private void loadData() {
        data = new ArrayList<>();        
        data.add("1first");
        data.add("2second");
        data.add("3third");
        data.add("4fourth");
        data.add("5fifth");
        data.add("6sixth");
        data.add("7seventh");
        data.add("8eighth");
        data.add("9ninth");
        data.add("10tenth");
    }

    public List<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setMessage(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return msg;
    }

    public String getTodo() {
        return todo;
    }
    public void setTodo(String t) {
        todo = t;
    }

    public void valueChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {
        String t = (String) ((UIOutput) e.getSource()).getValue();
        setMessage(t + " selected.");
    }

    public void deleteListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {
        if (data.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        String t = getTodo();
        setMessage(t + " deleted.");
        int ix = data.indexOf(t);
        data.remove(t);
        // select an item
        if (data.size() == 0) {
             setTodo("");
             return;
        }
        if (ix == data.size())  {
             ix = ix - 1;
        }
        t = data.get(ix);
        setTodo(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: As suggested in your other related post:tried a newer version?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have used version 5.1 instead of 5.0.

Comment: In your post you stated you already use 5.1. But it works now?

Comment: The problem as stated above in this post exists.

Comment: But after deleting and updating, is something selected server side (e.g. the previous element?) if not, it is completely normal to 'scroll to the top'…

Comment: In the bean code above see the deleteListener(). There is a comment called "// select an item": **after an item is deleted, another element is selected as specified in the code**.  In the GUI the item is selected according the code, correctly. But, the selected item is not seen, because the scroller moves to the top on its own. That means the selected item is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an article on scrolling to a selected row in a p:dataTable. The items in the table are sorted. After an add, update or delete the scroll bar scrolls to the selected item - and the selected item is visible. The jQuery script mentioned in the article can also be applied to the p:selectOneListBox.

[JSF p:dataTable - Scroll to Selected Row](http://www.javaquizplayer.com/blogposts/blogpost12.html)